# Function and arguments Issue | Unable to send command and connect to network device using python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, networking, cisco

Unable to produce from the device, made a separate function in running a simple method wherein I have a list of devices and command.

But from this script, seems like I can't send the command to the device? I'm not sure whether script can connect successfully. So I put a print on connect to device part just to determine the location.

From the output of the print is
Connected 0 <-from beg_rm
THIS IS THE COMMAND show ip int brief <-send_cmd

Would like to ask if my method is correct in connect and sending command using this function and argument?

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

#Required Modules
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/lab/Desktop/pexpect-2.3")
import sys, pexpect, re, getpass, threading, subprocess, os, time
#from queue import Queue

os.system("clear")


### TEST THE IP ADDRESS IF REACHABLE
def ping_ip(ip):
    #global gips
    rstlongstr = ''
    (output,error) = subprocess.Popen((['ping', ip, '-c', '2']), stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
    if b'bytes from' in output:
        #rstlongstr = rstlongstr + ip
        #print rstlongstr
    return "Reachable" + ip
    elif b'Host Unreachable' in output:
        return "Down"
    else:
        return "UNKNOWN"

### SEND COMMAND TO DEVICE
def send_cmd(child,com):
    print "THIS IS THE COMMAND", com
    child.sendline(com)
    child.expect("#")
    print(child.before)
    return result

### CONNECT TO DEVICE
def beg_rm(ip,uname,ppass,enpass):
    print "Begin remote connection",ip
    print "\nCRED",uname,ppass,enpass
    child = pexpect.spawn('ssh %s@%s' % (uname, ip))
    i = child.expect(['[P|p]assword: ','[U|u]sername: ','continue connecting (yes/no)?','#'],timeout=5)
    if i == 0:
        child.sendline(ppass)
    child.expect('>')
        child.sendline('enable')
        child.expect('Password: ')
        child.sendline(enpass)
    print "Connected 0"
    return i
    elif i == 1:
        child.sendline(uname)
        child.expect('Password: ')
        child.sendline(ppass)
        child.expect('>')
        child.sendline(enpass)
    print "Connected 1"
    return i
    elif i == 2:
        child.sendline('yes')
        i = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, '[P|p]assword: '])
        if i == 0:
        print "Error connecting ",ip
        return
    child.sendline(ppass)
        child.expect('>')
        child.sendline('enable')
        child.expect('Password: ')
        child.sendline(enpass)
    print "Connected 2"
        return i
    elif i == 3:
    pass


def main():
    print('-'*50)
    while True:
        print('------------------------- ue Network Tools -------------------------------')
        print('--- *********************************************************************** ---')
        print('-'*80)
        print'[1] Troubleshoot'
        print'[2] Custom Tshoot'
        print'[3] Wireless LAN'
        print'[4] Confinder'
        print'[q] exit\n'

        #Select Function
        input_select = raw_input('Please select a function: ')
        input_select = str(input_select)

        if input_select == 'q' or input_select == 'Q':
            sys.exit()
        elif input_select == '1':
            #Read the txt file
        devtxt = open('devices.txt')
            devlist  = devtxt.read().splitlines()
            print devlist
        cmdtxt = open('command.txt')
            cmdlist  = cmdtxt.read().splitlines()
        print cmdlist

            #tuname = raw_input("TACACS Username: ")
            #tpass=getpass.getpass("TACACS Password: ")
            #epass=getpass.getpass("Enable Password: ")

        tuname = "test"
            tpass = "test"
        epass = "enter"

        #LIST
        gips = []
        threadslist = []

            #Verify Reachability
            for ips in devlist:
                print "Processing the list to function", ips
                response = ping_ip(ips)
                result = ('%s \n' % (response))
        print result
                if re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})',str(response)):
            forgips = re.findall(r'(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})',str(response))
                    strgips = ''.join(forgips)
            #print "FORGIPS 2",strgips
            gips.append(strgips)
            pass
        else:
            pass

        print "\nList of reachable devices to be sent for threading:\n", gips

## LOOP REACHABLE DEVICE AND COMMAND
        for x in gips:
            child = beg_rm(x,tuname,tpass,epass)
            for y in cmdlist:
                    send_cmd(child,y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Trace back

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2jb.py", line 142, in <module>
    main()
  File "2jb.py", line 139, in main
    send_cmd(child,y)
  File "2jb.py", line 31, in send_cmd
    child.sendline(com)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sendline'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
child = beg_rm(x,tuname,tpass,epass)
for y in cmdlist:
    send_cmd(child,y)

def send_cmd(child,com):
    print "THIS IS THE COMMAND", com
    child.sendline(com)
    ...
```

`beg_rm()` returns an integer, which is then passed as the `child` argument to `send_cmd()`.

It seems like you're expecting `beg_rm()` to return the child object, instead of an integer?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but if I remove the for x statement where should I run the list of devices from devlist.txt? Didn't get your question sorry, but that I'm expecting receive from beg_rm session that will be use by send_cmd function.

Comment: The problem isn't the `for` loop.  The problem is you're passing an integer to `send_cmd()`, which then tries to treat it as a pexpect object.

Comment: Oks, Thanks.. But in this case how can I loop 2 list like cmdlist and devlist and pass to function. Should I loop the dev list the beg_rm function?